# ?isdtp=mn - Pop Task Page with no sidebar or headers

Tags: apex, visualforce, pagereference, sidebar, header

I have a custom button on Lead, "Log A Call", that pops a new window. The new window is the Task object edit page.

Currently "Log A Call" button pops: `/00T/e?title=Call&who_id={!Lead.Id}&followup=1&tsk5=Call&retURL=/{!Lead.Id}`

I want this same page to pop without the sidebar and header.

I thought to change the "Log A Call" button to display a Visualforce page, that has a pageReference to the url, and I would set header and sidebar = false.

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" controller="LogACallLeadController" action="{!goToTask}"></apex:page>

public class LogACallLeadController {
    public PageReference goToTask() {
    Id currentLeadId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/00T/e?title=Call&who_id='+currentLeadId+'&followup=1&tsk5=Call&retURL=/' + currentLeadId);
    return pageRef.setRedirect(true);
    }
}
```

This works but the header and sidebar are still visible. This is happening because of the redirect.

Is there a way to reference the specific URL in the visualforce page without using a redirect? Or is there an easier way to pop a new page with no sidebar or header of a standard object?

I also tried using  on the Standard Task object but it does not recognize the ownerId.

I also tried adding in: ?isdtp=mn to my URL with no success
`/00T/e?title=Call&who_id={!Lead.Id}&followup=1&tsk5=Call&retURL=/{!Lead.Id}?isdtp=mn`

[image: Custom Button - Log A Call]

[image: Button Populates this page WITH A HEADER AND SIDE BAR]

[image: I would like to populate the page with NO header and side bar]

Comment: can you put a picture of the issue you are facing

Comment: @SantanuBoral I updated with pictures. The first picture displays the custom button on the Lead object. The second picture displays the page I that pops when I click on the button. I want this page to populate in a new window with no header and sidebars.  The third picture is the custom button URL with the ?isdtp=mn on the end. I have tried a few different ways to get rid of the header and sidebar with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code behind javascript button works for me, it is **opening new window without sidebar and header**.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/31.0/connection.js")} 
var pageUrl = '{!URLFOR($Action.Activity.LogCall)}'; 
var parameters = '?title=Call&who_id={!Lead.Id}&isdtp=mn'; 
var link = pageUrl + parameters; 
window.open(link)
```

Comment: This works great! I am a little confused on the Activity.`LogCall` part and the `title=Call&who_id`. Do you have any documentation on these url patterns? Is this a standard way of populating a Activity page?

Comment: In formula window, select Field Type as `$Action`, it will list down of default salesforce provided actions. Btw, I have broken down URL and parameters in 2 parts

Comment: Interesting! So for the formula: {!URLFOR(target, id, [inputs], [no override])} - Activity.LogCall would be the target and there would be no id, inputs, or override?

Comment: @Santau - I am not sure if you will get this but I am just curious about the "why" behind adding the isdtp to the end of the Log A Call button. Why won't this work: `/00T/e?title=Call&who_id={!Lead.Id}&followup=1&tsk5=Call&retURL=/{!Lead.Id}?isdtp=mn` ?